# How do I use SendGatewayMessage to send a message to a Flex consumer?

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, blazeds

I have a CFC that occasionally needs to send a message via LCDS/BlazeDS to multiple Flex apps that have a consumer setup.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the specific steps to make this work.  Using ColdFusion 8 and Flex 3.

I know it's SendGatewayMessage but how do I configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit old but Ben Forta has a nice step by step intro on how to get started [on his blog](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/2/1/Getting-Started-With-ColdFusion-And-Flex-Enterprise-Services)